# Create a git submodule from already existing repository

Tags: git, version-control, git-submodules

I have the following folder tree:

```
<A git repository>
    <Folder A>
    <Folder B>
    <Another git repository C>
    <Yet another git repository D>
```

What I want is for repository C and D to be a submodule of the repository they are contained in. At the moment, C and D have not been added to the toplevel repository, they just reside in the folder. They got there by using `git clone`.
Is there a way to add them as submodules without having to delete the current folders and using `git submodule add <url to repository C>` to download them again?

Comment: I am not very familiar with sub-modules. Is there a reason why you can't do `git submodule add ./C` and `git submodule add ./D`?

Comment: That starts cloning it again